# "Insufficient content duration available" when playing a stream through the SmoothStreamingMediaElement

Tags: windows-phone-7, smooth-streaming

I am working on an application that features IIS Smooth Streaming using the SmoothStreamingMediaElement. Because of the nature of the project I can't disclose the source of the stream, I can however provide full technical information on the problem I encounter.

I seperated the SmoothStreaming part into a seperate application for testing purposes. Everything seems to be working well since the test stream provided by Microsoft works the way it should (http://video3.smoothhd.com.edgesuite.net/ondemand/Big%20Buck%20Bunny%20Adaptive.ism/Manifest)

I took the restrictions for SmoothStreaming on Windows Phone into account:
- In the ManifestReady event the available tracks are filtered to show only one available resolution
- The device is not connected through Zune while testing.

The error message presented is very clear:

> "3108 Insufficient content duration available to begin playback.
>   Available = 3840 ms, Required = 7250 ms"

I have not been able to find any references to this error. I did find some more information on where the required duration of 7250 ms originates from. [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.media.smoothstreaming.smoothstreamingmediaelement.liveplaybackoffset%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) suggests it has something to do with the LivePlaybackOffset which defaults at 7 seconds and cannot be changed in the WP7 SmoothStreamingMediaElement. The same code works fine in a browser-silverlight application.

I don't have direct access to the server providing the stream. Is there a way to address this issue clientside? Or does it require server-side configuration? If it helps I can share parts of the source code, please let me know what parts would be relevant. Your help is highly appreciated!

This is the manifest file:

```
<SmoothStreamingMedia MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="2" TimeScale="10000000" Duration="0" LookAheadFragmentCount="2" IsLive="TRUE" DVRWindowLength="300000000">
<StreamIndex Type="audio" QualityLevels="1" TimeScale="10000000" Name="audio" Chunks="7" Url="http://xxxx/xxx.isml/QualityLevels({bitrate})/Fragments(audio={start time})">
<QualityLevel Index="0" Bitrate="128000" CodecPrivateData="1190" SamplingRate="48000" Channels="2" BitsPerSample="16" PacketSize="4" AudioTag="255" FourCC="AACL"/>
<c t="3485836800000" d="38400000" r="7"/>
</StreamIndex>
<StreamIndex Type="video" QualityLevels="6" TimeScale="10000000" Name="video" Chunks="7" Url="http://xxxx/xxx.isml/QualityLevels({bitrate})/Fragments(video={start time})" MaxWidth="1024" MaxHeight="576" DisplayWidth="1024" DisplayHeight="576">
<QualityLevel Index="0" Bitrate="350000" CodecPrivateData="000000016742E01596540D0FF3CFFF80980097A440000003004000000CA10000000168CE060CC8" MaxWidth="405" MaxHeight="228" FourCC="AVC1" NALUnitLengthField="4"/>
<QualityLevel Index="1" Bitrate="700000" CodecPrivateData="000000016742E01E965404814F2FFF8140013FA440000003004000000CA10000000168CE060CC8" MaxWidth="568" MaxHeight="320" FourCC="AVC1" NALUnitLengthField="4"/>
<QualityLevel Index="2" Bitrate="1000000" CodecPrivateData="000000016742E01E965405217F7FFE0B800B769100000300010000030032840000000168CE060CC8" MaxWidth="654" MaxHeight="368" FourCC="AVC1" NALUnitLengthField="4"/>
<QualityLevel Index="3" Bitrate="1300000" CodecPrivateData="00000001674D4028965605819FDE029100000300010000030032840000000168EA818332" MaxWidth="704" MaxHeight="396" FourCC="AVC1" NALUnitLengthField="4"/>
<QualityLevel Index="4" Bitrate="1600000" CodecPrivateData="00000001674D402A965605A1AFCFFF80CA00CAA440000003004000000CA10000000168EA818332" MaxWidth="718" MaxHeight="404" FourCC="AVC1" NALUnitLengthField="4"/>
<QualityLevel Index="5" Bitrate="2000000" CodecPrivateData="00000001674D4032965300800936029100000300010000030032840000000168E96060CC80" MaxWidth="1024" MaxHeight="576" FourCC="AVC1" NALUnitLengthField="4"/>
<c t="3485836800000" d="38400000" r="7"/>
</StreamIndex>
</SmoothStreamingMedia>
```

Comment: I have been able to break the problem down to a clear issue. The player only loads the first fragment and never loads the next fragments. When the fragment length is shorther than the initial buffering time the error mentioned above shows. If we increase the fragment size on the server above the threshold of 7 seconds, the first fragment is played and than keeps buffering indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old but I had a very similar problem today, so I thought I should answer it...
The problem is with the r="7"
This parameter is not documented in the MS documentation and only found in Smooth Streaming version 2.2 and above (not 2.0).
r="7" means that the chunk in the manifest should be repeated 7 times, which means you have 7 * 3.84 sec in total.

There is a blog post which explains it here:
http://blogs.iis.net/samzhang/archive/2011/03/10/how-to-troubleshoot-live-smooth-streaming-issues-part-5-client-manifest.aspx

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to this. The issue has been solved with a workaround, but I will check if the client is still interested in the real solution. Thanks again!